# Error stating Module '"@angular/forms"' has no exported member 'UntypedFormGroup'. after updating to Angular 14.0.0

Tags: angular

I had an enterprise Angular application that was previously running on Angular **13.3.8** and updated to **14.0.0**, but am now having a problem where the app is auto-updated (component code) to import `UntypedFormBuilder` and `UntypedFormGroup` from `@angular/forms`. In same template, it replaced the following form group type from the following...

```
form: FormGroup;
```

to

```
form: UntypedFormGroup;
```

Getting following error:

```
Cannot find name 'UntypedFormBuilder'
```

Don't understand this. I've replaced some of these auto-conversion from update with regular FormGroup with now problem. It's going to be a pain to go back and remove this import and import FormGroup again, but if these have an advantage, I'd like to know wha it is, b/c I can't find any?

Solution: I just reverted all **UntypedFormBuilder** instances with **FormBuilder** instances.

Comment: you can check the updates https://angular.io/guide/update-to-latest-version#update-angular-cli-applications, try type again the form with form: FormGroup; and change the import

Comment: try deleting your node_modules folder and reinstalling the dependencies

Comment: Hi Joshua, do you find the reason why it updated itself after updating the angular version?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is an older question for angular 14 and I got my answer

Answer (score 2):

I also ran into this issue. A colleague had done the upgrade from Angular 13.x -> 14.x. The core of the issue is that I was still building and running the application using the older Angular 13.x.

Doing `npm install` updated Angular to the required version and the error went away.

Answer (score 0):

replace UntypedFormGroup with FormGroup , same thing for
{ UntypedFormControl,UntypedFormGroup,UntypedFormBuilder} replace ===>{ FormControl,FormGroup,FormBuilder}

Answer (score 0):

Running `npm ci` fixed this for me

Comment: Welcome to SO!  Although your insight may be valuable and solve the OP issue, it will be more instructive for him and others if you post some things that you tried before,  and failed. And, if possible, some link to docs or another source that pointed you for this solution.